# js - Sorting strings starting from a letter first and the length is higher, followed by strings starting from smaller to higher number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vuejs2

I have an array of object in which every object has a plate key, after a bit of trial and error (+ stackoverflow) i used this function:

```
sort(function(a, b) {
       return a.plate.toLowerCase() > b.plate.toLowerCase() ? a.plate.localeCompare(b.plate): -1;
});
```

which outputs this order.

```
[ "245/TAE.", "322(1)/SPA", "322(2)/SPA", "322(3)/SPA", "365/SDFA", "365/TRS", "964/ΜΕΝΤ."
, "SG/349(1)"
,"SG/349(3)"
,"SG/PASD."
,"SG/Χ''RAS."
,"SOTRA/Χ''SIMOTSEOY"]
```

This is somewhat of a viable option but my **desired outcome** is:

```
["SOTRA/Χ''IMOTSEOY", "SG/Χ''RAS.", "SG/PASD.", "SG/349(1)"
,"SG/349(3)"
, "245/TAE.", "322(1)/SPA", "322(2)/SPA", "322(3)/SPA", "365/SDFA", "365/TRS.", "964/ΜΕΝΤ."
]
```

Anything with only letters goes first, followed by first char being a letter followed by first char being a number in ascending order.

I did try some variations of reversing the elements or with a regex but its not yielding the desired outcome.

Using Vuejs on the front end, and here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sidirgot/mn46L2rk/3/) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a custom sorting order, you need a more complex sorting function. There are many possible ways to do it, but a scoring function will work (maybe cache this value, depending on the number of items)

```
function scoreIt(n){
  // does n contain any digits?
  if(/[0-9]/.test(n)){
    // is the first char a letter?
    if(/^[a-z]/.test(n)){
      return 1;  // first char is a letter and there are digits somewhere
    }else{
      return 2;  // first char is not a letter
    }
  }else{
    return 0;    // no digits
  }
}
```

then, in your sorting function, use it as:

```
let a0 = a.plate.toLowerCase(), b0 = b.plate.toLowerCase(),
  a1 = scoreIt(a0), b1 = scoreIt(b0);
if(a1 == b1){
  // your original code
  return a0 > b0 ? a.plate.localeCompare(b.plate): -1;
} else {
  return a1-b1;
}
```

Comment: I will play around with your suggested solution later in the day, and i will get back to you with the results.

Comment: The solution is working like a charm except one edge case in which the plate is only letters and the length of the plate i bigger than the rest of the only letter plates, in which case it has to go first. Is there a way to achieve this without refactoring the entire function?

Comment: instead of returning 0 in the score function when no digits are found, you can return `-n.length`. that will make longer plates have higher priority in the sort